# node.js android opening up port and finding ip adress

Tags: java, android, node.js

```html
var app= require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io= require('socket.io')(http);
io.on('connection',(socket)=>{
  console.log('Client ${socket.id} has been connected');

  
});
http.listen(3000,()=>{
  console.log('Server is listening on port 3000');
});
```

Hi guys I am trying to get my app working. right now my app works locally on my wifi, however I want to make it global. I need to open up a port, which is done. and find my public ip adress. I think I have both done according to http://ip4.me/ I placed in my public ip. also according to my netstat -an my 3000 port should be open its listening. however my code isn't working. can someone please help , I'm a noob, I really would appreciate your guys help!!

**How can I check if im doing this right?**

Comment: thought i found the answer by using my ipv4 didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got it working, all I had to do was first make sure my server was listening to information from the port I was trying to acess. from there I needed to open the port with windows firewall, and finally do some port forwardding for my router. I would suggest youtubing your router for forwarding because they can be tricky, and different. Hope this helps someone. Please make sure to be listening on your server for information before checking for information , otherwise I got nothing but 2 days of a head ache.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure port forwarding from your router to your machine.

Since you're probably behind NAT, your request reaches the router but the router has no idea who you really want to connect to, so if you set-up port forwarding the router will "know" that all requests to your public IP in port 3000 have to go to your machine (i.e 10.0.0.3).

I'd recommend using a hosting service instead of hosting the server on your PC since it can expose you to threats, there are several good free hosting sites. 
you can use heroku / google cloud

you can use this article as reference: https://managewp.com/how-to-access-a-local-website-from-internet-with-port-forwarding

Comment: thanks for the tips bro! but im trying to host on my pc

Comment: in that case, setup port forwarding :)

Comment: bro i did, but it wont work? how do i confirm my port forward is set up correctly? i followed a example on wiki. mine seems to be working

Comment: Hey guys I had it working wanted to post my answer, but for some reason now i cant even open a port? I had it all working perfectly, any help